Need to update Drop down used in HTML + Django
I have developed Django web application and in that I have used drop down field using the code:
<select id="countrynamew" name="countrynamew" value="{{countrynamew}}">
  <option value="Abkhazia">Abkhazia</option>
  <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
  <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
</select>

How can I able to assign the selected value from Python code. And I have tried the code:
countrynamew = 'Abkhazia'
out = ('countrynamew': countrynamew)
return render(request, 'xxx.html', out )

But, it does not assigns the value and how can I assign the value? Please suggest

You have placed value="{{countrynamew}}" in the wrong place.
It should be like this:
<select id="countrynamew" name="countrynamew">
  <option value="Abkhazia" {% if countrynamew == "Abkhazia" %}selected{% endif %}>Abkhazia</option>
  <option value="Afghanistan" {% if countrynamew == "Afghanistan" %}selected{% endif %}>Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="Albania" {% if countrynamew == "Albania" %}selected{% endif %}>Albania</option>
  <option value="Algeria" {% if countrynamew == "Algeria" %}selected{% endif %}>Algeria</option>
</select>

This code will add the selected attribute to the option which is selected by the python.
